# How to set hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.initialDelay in Jenkins kubernetes plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I get the attribute of hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.initialDelay in Jenkins kubernetes plugin from Jenkins API,but I don't know How to set hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.initialDelay with user interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set it from the UI, you have to start Jenkins with that Java 
system property

```
-Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.initialDelay=0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed `Jenkins` on `Kubernetes` itself, 
You can set this under `env` var `JAVA_OPTS` in your `Kubernetes YAML` file like :

```
 env:
 - name: JAVA_OPTS
   value: "-Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.initialDelay=0 -Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.MARGIN=50 -Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.MARGIN0=0.85"
```

You can find such YAML file at [Jenkins Kubernete Plugin's Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/src/main/kubernetes/jenkins.yml) repo itself.